# What cloud-sync software provides this functionality?

Tags: backup, file-synchronization

*(X-post from SuperUser)*

I currently use LiveDrive but I am looking to migrate. This is not a "recommend me" thread in that I seek pros and cons, which are subject to change and sway to opinion; instead, I am looking for service software that utilises a similar feature to LiveDrive's in its Briefcase functionality.

LiveDrive Briefcase, when installed, creates a network drive at L:. This is actually a folder stored locally, but all management is conducted through Windows Explorer, which is a big plus because I hate dealing with badly-designed vendor apps.

[image: Network drive]

If you opt (as I do) to *not* sync files automatically, LiveDrive Briefcase will instead create entities of all the files you have stored for syncing online, replicating the file structure. Files that are not synced locally take up 0KB and have a file extension of .LD. Users are able to right-click individual files or folders and sync them locally, or to delete the local copy and keep the file stored solely on the cloud.

[image: Selective file sync]

What other software offers this functionality? It is a deal-breaker for me.

Comment: This is software recommendations __not__ _service_ recommendations. Please reword to fit the site premise.

Comment: OK, reworded to be more software-centric.

Comment: My close vote retracted.

Comment: Do you search something like the placeholder files OneDrive had in Win8? (I hate that they removed this feature)

Comment: quite possibly. i'm not crazy about onedrive, but if they're looking to bring it back it looks like they might be the only option; dropbox infinity requires kernel-level OS access which i'm not happy about and their prices are completely unreasonable.

Comment: @seagull, have you found any variants?

Comment: @Suncatcher no, nothing yet.